# Taking the average from 3d array without zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I want to take the X(avg) from the axis= 1 of this matrix  of shape(5,10,15) but without taking into account any zero vectors in the average. The average matrix must be of shape (5,15).
If i try to implement the `np.average(l,axis=1)` function i am taking a matrix of shape (5,15) but the zero vectors is still inside.

```
[[[ 9 19  6  2 13  4 19 11 19 15 14  2 16  4  2]
  [13 11  3 14 12  4 10 11 11  6 10  3 12  1  1]
  [12  9 17  5  9 10 17  9 12  2 16  9 10  2 14]
  [17 17 15 19  7 18 18  5  9 11 14 14  3 10  2]
  [ 9  3 13 19 18 18 17  5 16  5  2 15 19 16 12]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 9 11 10 12 12 12 10  9 18 16 15  2 11 17 12]
  [ 5 13 18 19 17 13  8  8  1  4  7  7 12 10 14]
  [ 9  3 13 19 18 18 17  5 16  5  2 15 19 16 12]
  [ 9 11 10 12 12 12 10  9 18 16 15  2 11 17 12]]

 [[ 5 13 18 19 17 13  8  8  1  4  7  7 12 10 14]
  [ 5 13 18 19 17 13  8  8  1  4  7  7 12 10 14]
  [18  7 16  9  8 14 19 15 12  3 15 15  8  7  4]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [18  7 16  9  8 14 19 15 12  3 15 15  8  7  4]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [16  5  3  6  8 16  9  2  7 12 16 14 19  4 17]
  [19  4 10  4 15 12  4  3  2  1 17 16  8  2  6]
  [ 9 11 10 12 12 12 10  9 18 16 15  2 11 17 12]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 9  3 13 19 18 18 17  5 16  5  2 15 19 16 12]
  [ 2 11  6  4 13  6 11  5  3 15  9 13 13 18  9]
  [13  7 15 10  2  5  5  2 10  1 10 14 12  9  6]
  [ 9 19  6  2 13  4 19 11 19 15 14  2 16  4  2]
  [ 4 10 11 19 11  5  3 14 19 11  2  1 15  6 10]
  [11 12 16  9  8 16 19  8 12  1 19 16  1  8 17]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [11 12 16  9  8 16 19  8 12  1 19 16  1  8 17]
  [ 9  3 13 19 18 18 17  5 16  5  2 15 19 16 12]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [11 12 16  9  8 16 19  8 12  1 19 16  1  8 17]
  [19  2  3  5  2 12  1  8 10  9 12 16 17 16 15]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [13 11  3 14 12  4 10 11 11  6 10  3 12  1  1]
  [ 9 19  6  2 13  4 19 11 19 15 14  2 16  4  2]
  [12  9 17  5  9 10 17  9 12  2 16  9 10  2 14]
  [ 5 13 18 19 17 13  8  8  1  4  7  7 12 10 14]
  [18  7 16  9  8 14 19 15 12  3 15 15  8  7  4]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 9 19  6  2 13  4 19 11 19 15 14  2 16  4  2]
  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 9 11 10 12 12 12 10  9 18 16 15  2 11 17 12]
  [19  2  3  5  2 12  1  8 10  9 12 16 17 16 15]
  [10 19  7  9  5  7  5  1 15  8 19  7 15 10 12]
  [12  9 17  5  9 10 17  9 12  2 16  9 10  2 14]
  [ 5 13 18 19 17 13  8  8  1  4  7  7 12 10 14]
  [13 11  3 14 12  4 10 11 11  6 10  3 12  1  1]
  [19  4  9 17 10 13 10 17 12 13  9  8 12 10 15]
  [ 9 11 10 12 12 12 10  9 18 16 15  2 11 17 12]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **weights** of `np.average` to skip the zeros very easily:

```py
np.average(v, axis=1, weights=v>0)
```

Output result:

```py
array([[10.22222222, 10.77777778, 11.66666667, 13.44444444, 13.11111111,
        12.11111111, 14.        ,  8.        , 13.33333333,  8.88888889,
        10.55555556,  7.66666667, 12.55555556, 10.33333333,  9.        ],
       [12.85714286,  8.57142857, 13.        , 11.14285714, 12.14285714,
        13.42857143, 11.        ,  8.57142857,  7.57142857,  6.14285714,
        13.14285714, 10.85714286, 11.14285714,  8.14285714, 10.14285714],
       [ 8.5       ,  9.625     , 12.        , 11.375     , 11.375     ,
        11.        , 13.75      ,  7.25      , 13.375     ,  6.75      ,
         9.625     , 11.5       , 12.        , 10.625     , 10.625     ],
       [12.42857143, 10.42857143, 11.28571429,  9.        ,  9.85714286,
        10.42857143, 13.28571429, 10.        , 11.        ,  5.71428571,
        13.28571429,  9.71428571, 10.85714286,  6.85714286,  9.57142857],
       [11.66666667, 11.        ,  9.22222222, 10.55555556, 10.22222222,
         9.66666667, 10.        ,  9.22222222, 12.88888889,  9.88888889,
        13.        ,  6.22222222, 12.88888889,  9.66666667, 10.77777778]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Count nonzero values by the axis, then sum by the axis, and then divide the count by the sum. It's the only way, since you want only the nonzeros.